# How do I check, programmatically, which targets are available in a cubin?

Tags: cuda, cuda-driver, fatbin

Suppose I have a cubin file, or perhaps to make it easier, a cubin file I loaded into memory (so that I have a `void*` to the data).

Using the [CUDA Driver API for modules](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-driver-api/group__CUDA__MODULE.html), I can try loading the data into a module within the current context; and this would fail if compiled code is not available for a relevant target (and there's no PTX which could be JITed instead). But - what I actually want to do is check which targets have code in the module data (or module file)?

Non-programmatically, I know I can invoke:

```
cuobjdump my.fatbin
```

and get a listing of what's in there. But I want to do it from within my application's code.

Is this possible?

Comment: Not as far as I am aware

Comment: Also loading a cubin without compiled code for the current GPU won’t necessarily fail with an error *if* there is a usable PTX file which can be JIT compiled into the current module

Comment: @talonmies: Yes, certainly, clarified.

Answer (score 1):

You could call cuobjdump from within your program and parse its output.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>

__global__
void kernel(){

}

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    std::string command{};
    command += "cuobjdump ";
    command += argv[0];
    command += " > out.txt";

    int sysret = system(command.c_str());
    kernel<<<1,1>>>();
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    return sysret;
}
```

Comment: Well, yes, fair enough, but that's not what I meant, plus I'll need to correctly parse this.

Answer (score 0):

#### You may be able do this using an ELF parser.

It seems that cubin files are actually slightly-non-standard [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) files. Specifically, they have an `.nv_fatbin` ELF section, containing regions with compiled code for different targets; see [this analysis](https://zenodo.org/record/2339027/files/decoding-cuda-binary-file-format.pdf).

If you used an ELF library, and made it accept some invalid/different magic numbers / version numbers, it would probably parse the cubin file in a way you could then easily extract your meta-data of interest from, including the target architecture for each region.

See also how a cubin file is *generated*, using an ELF library, [here](https://github.com/daadaada/turingas/blob/master/turingas/cubin.py) (but note that's Python code with a lot of magic numbers and somewhat difficult to follow).

Now it's just the "simple matter of coding", adapting an ELF parser to collect and expose what you need. The remaining question is whether all of the relevant information is in the ELF meta-data or whether you also need to do further parsing of the contents.

Comment: So your edit kind of invalidates this idea. You would need to get the magic parsing to check binary payloads, then parse the PTX for compatibility, where it exists. That’s a *lot* of work

Comment: @talonmies: If there are easily-parsable ELF fields with "XY" architecture values, then I don't see why there's a lot of work. If there's non-ELF parsing to be done, then you would be right. But the link it suggests it's not that bad. Still, I'll qualify my optimism somewhat.

Comment: All of the GPU specific stuff are contained in an NVIDIA specific `.nv` section. They are not documented AFAIK and I don't think the standard ELF parsers would work with them. So there is a lot of reverse engineering in your future if you want to do this (thus my original comment on your question)